# How can I tell if I drilled too far into a ceiling joist?

Tags: ceiling, hanging

I am trying to hang a U-hook for a swing/chair in my son’s room. I used a stud finder to locate a stud/joint on a popcorn ceiling. When drilling the cross recessed screws into the ceiling, It was difficult to drill at first with loud vibrations) which made me believe it was the stud) about half way through it brakes and just goes in easy. The screw however does not stay, it just slides back out of the ceiling half way. I have attempted to measure 16 and 24 inches across, knock, and have drilled down the same vertical spot with the same result. I also have expansion bolts. Should I be using those? What am I doing wrong? Is this not the joint? Are the screws too long? Thanks for all of your help.

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Comment: Ceiling joists/rafters should be at least 3 and a half inches deep.  You probably just hit the edge and split the wood a bit(no bigy) or have found a furring, a thinner piece of wood.

Comment: How big, (wide not deep) of a hole are you drilling and what screws are you using?

Comment: I am using cross recessed countersunk head screws

Comment: Since you mention vibration, I think that you drilled through some metal.  Are you able to go above the ceiling to have a look ?  If its  a newish house, it may well be ceiling battens.

Comment: I would not trust a swing on a ceiling joist unless I could see how the joist was constructed. Unless this is just for an infant? A person is just too heavy. For example if you hit some blocking meant for drywall it will seem strong enough - at first. Until it's not. Cut an access hole in the drywall and stick a camera up there.

Answer (score 1):

That is a lag screw.

It is likely you drilled the hole too big.  More likely you drilled into a piece of wood that is only supporting the ceiling drywall. (dead wood) This is a 2x4 that is laid on the wide face rather than the edge. This is why you felt force against the drill then no force.  You drilled through the 1 1/2" side.

That is not enough support to hang anything over about 2 or 3 pounds from. Anything heavier and you risk pulling the ceiling down in that area.

Comment: So how would I find the actual joint from that or insure I’m not drilling into the “dry wood”

Comment: Use your stud finder and locate an area that shows only 1 1/2 inches of density.  This is most likely a joist or  the bottom cord of a truss. (You didn't indicate if the bedroom was on the first floor or second, so we don't know what is most likely the make up of the structure supporting the ceiling.

Comment: It is a one story house. So the first floor. Older home built in 1977

Comment: you need to figure which way the bottom cord of trusses run, or the roof framing. This will tell you which direction the main support of the ceiling  runs.  Then look for the 1 1/2 inch density indication from your stud finder.

Comment: Thank you, for all of your help.

Comment: If you bend a coat hanger into a square “U” with 12” to a side, you can feed it into a hole and twist it around to hit trusses or joists.